# Get top x% rows for every unique value in column by other column value

Tags: sql, sqlite, greatest-n-per-group, percentage

Table "tags":

```
Source  Target      Weight
#003    blitzkrank  0.83
#003    deutsch     0.7
#003    brammen     0.57
#003    butzfrauen  0.55
#003    solaaaa     0.5
#003    moments     0.3
college scandal     1.15
college prosecutors 0.82
college students    0.41
college usc         0.33
college full house  0.17
college friends     0.08
college house       0.5
college friend      0.01
```

The table has 5.600.000 rows and ~91.000 unique entries in column "Source".

For every unique value in "Source" and "Target" I need the top x% rows (e.g. top 20%, top 30%, needs to be variable) by Weight (table is sorted by "Source" (ascending) and "Weight" (descending).

- If rows have the same "Weight" take rows in alphabetical order.
- If x% == 0 take at least one row.

Since there will be duplicates (e.g. "Source = "college" will yield at least one duplicate row as "Target" = "scandal") duplicated entries should be removed if possible. Otherwise not a big deal.

Calculation for "Source":

```
6 rows where Source = "#003", 6 * 0.2 = 1.2 = take 1 row
8 rows where Source = "college", 8 * 0.2 = 1.6 = take 2 rows
```

Needed result table for "Source":

```
Source  Target      Weight
#003    blitzkrank  0.83
college scandal     1.15
college prosecutors 0.82
```

How can I do that in SQL in an SQLite database?

Comment: "For every unique value in "Source" and "Target" I need the top x% rows "  I don't understand what you mean.  Do you mean for the "pair" of values?  Can a row be repeated, once for source and once for target?

Comment: A row can be repeated once for source and once for target, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a sample by `source`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by source order by weight desc, target) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by source) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 or  -- always at least one row
      seqnum <= round(cnt * 0.2);
```

Based on your example, I think this is what you want.  You can construct a similar query for `target`.

Comment: This gives the needed result, thank you very much. Is there a way to to the same for Column "Target" in the same SQL query so that it gets the rows for both in one run?

Comment: @Vega you can use a `UNION` of two queries (which also removes duplicates).

Comment: Good to know, UNION takes 5,71 minutes, great speed up (took 1-2 days) compared to my solution in Python/Pandas. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: @Vega Adding indexes on the source and target columns (If they don't already exist) should help speed that up if it's something you need to run frequently. Or see the [sqlite3 shell's .expert command](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#index_recommendations_sqlite_expert_) for detailed index recommendations.